# what is the proper ng2 implementation sequence for refreshing component display based on dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

What is the proper ng2 implementation sequence for refreshing a component display based on dropdown selection? I have a users.component and a users.service which searches (posts) for users based on a provided request object.

The users component html template has a Region dropdown. When a site user selects the Region dropdown, a list of users belonging to the selected region should be displayed in the component based on the selected region.

What would be the proper way to pass the request object to the users.service? The users.service should not build this request object, of course, only accept it. In traditional js, I would bind to the click event of the dropdown to call a refreshDisplay() function which gets the selected value, builds a request object and makes an ajax call with the request object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In traditional js, I would bind to the click event of the dropdown to call a refreshDisplay() function which gets the selected value, builds a request object and makes an ajax call with the request object.

That's exactly what you'll do in Angular, except instead of directly interacting with the browser event, you'll use Angular's abstraction:

```
<select (change)="someMethod()">
...options
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks Kai!  I put the ng2 change hook you mentioned in the select control and I put a corresponding js function in the component for event handling. Let's say I wire up a (change) in 2 selects with that function call: opt1, opt2. Whenever the change event occurs in 1 of the selects, the triggered function should get the selected values from both opt1 and opt2 as search criteria values. What would be the proper way to get those select values from the component? For example, in jQuery I would just get the value like $('#opt1').val().

Comment: @user8334943 that's probably a separate question which you should ask a new one for :) And you will probably find your answer in the [Angular forms documentation here](https://angular.io/guide/forms)

Comment: Looks like Renderer and ElementRef have been or are being deprecated.  I need to find the latest way to do this in a basic component